# Default UISwitch to YES then save state with NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, uiswitch

The functionality I'm trying to get to is to default the state of my switch to `setOn:YES` but once the user toggles the `UISwitch` save the state of that switch in `NSUserDefaults`.

How would I best go about this in my view? I currently have the code below in my `viewDidLoad`:

```
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"lights"] == 0){
        [lightsSwitch setOn:NO];
}
```

and in my `toggleLightSwitch:(id)sender`:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:lightsSwitch.isOn
                                            forKey:@"lights"];
```

but the functionality will be to default to `setOn:NO`. Since `NSUserDefault` defaults to `NO` for a bool key, is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: The "proper" way to set default values in your defaults is to use `-[NSUserDefaults registerDefaults:]`

Comment: 0 is not equal to YES.

Comment: @ParagBafna yep i'm trying to say that on load if it's 0, then display the switch as off.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`NSUserDefaults` starts empty, so asking for a key returns `nil`, and calling `-boolValue` on nil returns `NO`/0

You should use `-[NSUserDefaults registerDefaults:]` to set defaults for your keys/values in `-appDidFinishLaunching` in your app delegate:

```
-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication*)app
{
    NSDictionary * defaults = @{
        "lights" : @YES
        // you can list the default values for other defaults/switches here
    } ;
    [ [ NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults ] registerDefaults:defaults ] ;
}
```

In your `-viewDidLoad`, do this:

```
lightsSwitch.on = [ [ NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults ] boolForKey:@"lights" ] ;
```

In your toggleLightSwitch, I would to this:

```
BOOL isOn = [ [ NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults ] boolForKey:@"lights" ] ;
isOn = !isOn ; // toggle ;
[ NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults ] setBool:isOn ForKey:@"lights" ] ;
self.lightsSwitch.on = isOn ;
```

Comment: won't `didFinishLaunching` fire every app launch though? This would automatically reset the switch every time?

Comment: no--registerDefaults only sets the original defaults. it doesn't replace any values already set. see the docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000318-CIHDDCDB

Comment: alright let me try. is this the most scalable solution for lets say 10 switches also?

Comment: this looks good. only question is do I have to do this 10x :P?

Comment: No.. let's say your switches are controlled by defaults "lights", "camera", "action", change the dictionary above to be `@{ "lights":@YES, "camera":@YES, @"action":@YES }` for example

Comment: Or maybe it's just an array: `@{ "lights":@[ @YES, @YES, @YES, @YES, ..., @YES ]}`. Then you use it like (for switch #3): `switch.on = [ [ [ [ NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults ] objectForKey:@"lights" ] objectAtIndex:3 ] boolValue ]`

Answer (score 0):

If the default state is 'YES', you can set NSUserDefualt value to YES when the app run at the first time, or you can use an enum value, with an extra value saying the value hasn't been set yet.

Comment: You should use `-[NSUserDefaults registerDefaults:]`

Answer (score 0):

You set in **Yes** to `lights` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method, for checking that app is running first time.

```
  if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"lights"]==nil)
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool:YES forKey:@"lights"];
    }
```

Comment: It's probably better to use `[NSUserDefaults registerDefaults:]`. That's explicitly for setting default values for your defaults.

Comment: This makes the most sense to me right now - but how scalable is this if I have 10 switches?

Answer (score 0):

First You should set the boolValue to YES in your NSUserDefaults for @"lights" key and then use if to check if the value is YES then set the UISwitch value to YES or No depending the boolValue in NSUserDefaults.

in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` write

```
NSDictionary *defaults = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:YES, @"lights", nil];

  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:defaults];
```

in your `-viewDidLoad` method write

```
UISwitch *mySwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
mySwitch.on = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"lights"];;
[mySwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(toggleLightSwitch:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

and in your toggles method check the value and set the appropriate value in NSUserDefaults

```
 -(void)toggleLightSwitch:(id)sender {

    if (!sender.on) {

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"lights"]; 
    }
    else
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"lights"];

    }
}
```

Comment: I think this will reset the user default every view load.

Comment: yes as nielsbot said in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method you need to  register the nsuserdefaults. That will solve the problem.